# TinyMCE : Create a Custom Color Split Button

Tags: button, tinymce, custom-controls, color-picker

I am trying to create a custome color dropdown/split button in TinyMCE.  The API seems capable of this but I have not had success in my tests.  I am trying to use the createColorSplitButton method.  Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({ 
    mode : "exact", 
    elements : "content",
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fontselect,fontsizeselect,custombackground", 
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "", 
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

setup : function(ed) {
    ed.controlManager = new tinymce.ControlManager(ed);

    ed.controlManager.createColorSplitButton('custombackground', {
        title : 'Background Color',
        image : 'icon.gif',
        onclick : function() {
            // change iFrame background 
        }
    });
}
}); 

</script>
<textarea id="content" name="content" cols="50" rows="15">This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE.</textarea>
```

So I need to get this to add a new color split button to the toolbar.  After that I would need the split button to actually change the color of the iFrame.  Any help would be greatly appreciated !

EDIT : I have created a fiddle for anyone interested in helping :
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/dwcaab

Comment: i will give you a hand i f you create a tinymce fiddle with what you tried already

Comment: Ive added the fiddle here : http://fiddle.tinymce.com/dwcaab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a tinymce [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/lwcaab/16) on base of yours. Please check this and tell me if this is what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This is amazing! I shall name my first born in your honor!

Comment: hehe, glad to have been able to help. I remember myself two years ago trying to create a custom tinymce dropdown-button which took me pretty long

Comment: Hi,this example is not working.Can you please tell me the version no of tinymce that you have used?

Comment: since this answer dates back to 2012 it is concerning tinymce 3, for tinymce 4 this is something totally different